# Overriding WPF OnStartUp results in multiple window instances

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In a simple MVVM approach I link the MainWindow to a ViewModel by overriding OnStartup in App.xaml.

```
  public partial class App : Application
  {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);

      MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
      var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
      window.DataContext = viewModel;
      window.Show();
    }

  }
```

This results in two instances of the MainWindow when I run the WPF application. Shouldn't it only result in one as I am overriding the startup?

One of the window is showing the correct DataContext (ViewModel), while the other is not.

Comment: Alex Curtis already gave the right answer. To explain it: You just create another window in your startup event, the ApplicationStartupUri just tells wpf "Please create this window for me after you finished loading". You could also place the DataContext assignment in the window itself, after the Initialize Components.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

Remove The StartupUri. That will stop that second window loading.

Comment: Thanks! @Alex. When working on multiple views and navigation, don't figure out what's wrong. You save my day.